# Windows Scheduled Task and Windows Form application

Tags: windows-7, tasks, forms

I have a windows form application that is using a WebBrowser control, I want to run this in a schedulded task on my windows 7 machine, but when I run it, the program doesn't seem to save any web pages (which is what the application is supposed to do)

I've been reading up and at this point I"m not even sure if this is possible, does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure there is no problem when you run it as Normally ?

Comment: Yes, when I lanuch it through the command line, I can see the pages been saved to files

Comment: Say what you did do, Exactly. Are you using your application from Command-Line??

Comment: I am using a Scheduled task to launch the program via command line passing in 2 arguments, the application is a windows forms application because it uses the WebBrowser control

Comment: I'm having kind of the same behavior. I have a commandline tool, that launches a winforms application with a WebBrowser with `DockStyle=Fill`. Running the commandline through cmd works, but through Schedule tasks, it doesn't. Also not with given answer to use `cmd.exe /k`. In my case, when run through schedule tasks, the WebBrowser control is larger then the winforms, even though the DockStyle is set.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Action program to 'cmd.exe' then you can put your application path and argamets like :
cmd.exe /k [PATH2APP] [ARGAMENTS]

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your solution.  This is a widnows form application, are you saying cmd.exe /k "C:/scraper/scraper.exe" "argument1" "argument2" - like this?

Comment: Yes! but argaments must be out of <"> symbols.

Comment: I tried the way that I though you mentioned, and still not saving any files to the hard drive.  No error messages are being logged either